# Spring Boot Application not connecting to Apache ActiveMQ Artemis using native configuration

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I have a spring-boot application that has to connect to a deployed Apache Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.9.0 broker.

The broker has the default configuration listening to the 61616 port.

I've got a library where I have encapsulated the calls to the broker. The pom.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xxx.ems.microservice.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>ems-ms-core-library</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>EMSMSCoreLibrary</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
  </parent>  


  <properties>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
          <artifactId>artemis-jms-server</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.apm</groupId>
            <artifactId>apm-agent-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcabi-manifests</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

My configuration file includes the following lines to connect to the artemis broker:

```
spring:
  artemis:
     mode: native
     host: myhost
     port: 61616
  # Spring JMS Settings
  jms:
    template:
      qos-enabled: true
```

Here I include the method I'm using to send the messages

```
package com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.queue;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

// Apache Artemis Message Sender
@Component
@EnableJms
public class MessageSender {
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    MessageConverter defaultMessageConverter;

    protected void send(String destinationQueue, EMSFileMessage emsFileMessage, int ... priority) throws EMSQueueException{
        try{
            if (priority.length == 0){
                jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, emsFileMessage);
            }else{
                jmsTemplate.setPriority(priority[0]);
                jmsTemplate.send(destinationQueue, new MessageCreator() {
                    @Override
                    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                        return defaultMessageConverter.toMessage(emsFileMessage, session);
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch(UncategorizedJmsException ex){
            throw new EMSQueueException("Fatall error, probably due to connection with message broker, address that is trying to connect with address "+destinationQueue, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Before calling the send message I'm writing a log to check the ArtemisProperties (host and port) and both have the proper values. The destinationQueue has also the correct value.

For some reason I've got the following exception

```
com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.queue.EMSQueueException: Fatall error, probably due to connection with message broker, address that is trying to connect with address ems.gnfr
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.queue.MessageSender.send(MessageSender.java:56) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.queue.MessageDispatcher.sendFile(MessageDispatcher.java:41) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.queue.MessageDispatcher.send(MessageDispatcher.java:33) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.msdiskloader.controller.DiskLoaderController.processSingleFile(DiskLoaderController.java:64) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.msdiskloader.controller.DiskLoaderController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7f37b3f5.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.apm.aspects.AspectTransactionStarter.doMessageReception(AspectTransactionStarter.java:24) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.msdiskloader.controller.DiskLoaderController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eca14b7b.processSingleFile(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.msdiskloader.utils.DirectoryChangesWatcher.lambda$proccesExistingFilesInPath$2(DirectoryChangesWatcher.java:249) ~[classes/:?]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.msdiskloader.utils.DirectoryChangesWatcher.proccesExistingFilesInPath(DirectoryChangesWatcher.java:249) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.msdiskloader.utils.DirectoryChangesWatcher.startWatchingFolder(DirectoryChangesWatcher.java:94) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.msdiskloader.controller.DiskLoaderController.onApplicationStart(DiskLoaderController.java:46) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) [spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) [spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.app.EMSMicroserviceApplication.run(EMSMicroserviceApplication.java:10) [classes/:?]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.msdiskloader.MicroserviceApplication.main(MicroserviceApplication.java:18) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.queue.MessageSender.send(MessageSender.java:45) ~[classes/:?]
    ... 52 more
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:846) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:282) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:277) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:494) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.queue.MessageSender.send(MessageSender.java:45) ~[classes/:?]
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:797) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:844) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:282) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:277) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:494) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.queue.MessageSender.send(MessageSender.java:45) ~[classes/:?]
    ... 52 more
```

I have seen another exception with debug level that might be related. It is

```
 Unable to load the library 'netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64', trying other loading mechanism.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64 in java.library.path
```

Is there anything that should be installed? I'm new with artemis and such kind of brokers.
Any help would be appreciated